# Solving a system of linear equations with $3$ equations and $4$ unknowns but can be row-reduced to just one column.

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

This title sounds reaaaaally vague and specific, but I'll get specific. I've run across a system of linear equations for a homework problem that I can't solve with echelon form nor $Ax = b$.

Here's the question in question (haha):

-
[image]

So, I can either reduce the matrix of equations into echelon form, or find $A^{-1}$ and multiply it by $b$. The problem with the $Ax=b$ method though is that I solve it by writing the matrix of coefficients with parameters, then the identity matrix beside it, and do row operations on both, however the matrix of coefficients with parameters *is not square*, so my identity matrix is not square, and thus that isn't an identity matrix, so there's that complication.

When reducing to echelon form, I run into some odd circumstances. Take this one, for example:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
        1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$R3 \rightarrow R3 - R1$$

$$R2 \rightarrow R2-R1$$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$R2 \rightarrow R2 + R3$$
$$R3 \rightarrow R3 + R2$$
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

So.. uh.. I'm kind of stuck. I'm fairly confident this a row equivalent matrix, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what else to do. Both my tools to solve this problem have been exhausted. Since this is homework, I'm obviously not asking for an answer, but for some guidance - explaining why my tools aren't working (or at least why they seem to not be) and hint at what to do to rectify this.

Comment: As a sidenote: You can't do $R2\rightarrow R2+R3$ and $R3\rightarrow R3+R2$ at the same time.  The way row reduction works is that you apply one step at a time to attain an equivalent set of equations; you can do $R3\rightarrow R3-R1$ and $R2\rightarrow R2-R1$ at the same time because you get the same result as if you did them one step at a time.

Comment: On snap - is what I did basically just replace a row with a zero row in my calculation?

Comment: I can say that what you did results in the same thing as replacing a row with 0, but I cannot say if that is what is going through your head when you try and expand out the steps.  But given that you are asking that question, I would say probably it is.

Comment: Yep. Your row-reduction was invalid. The $R3\to R3+R2$ step shouldn’t have changed anything since you’d already zeroed out row 2.

Comment: Interesting. Because my justification for that operation is because $R2$ and $R3$ are self-contained rows and implications of the original system, and based on the belief that I could hypothetically keep columns in the back of my mind and use them  later, like doing something like $R4 \rightarrow R4 + oldR3$ since $oldR3$ is just equal to some constant, an implication of the system, and the same as doing something like $12 + 5 = 17$, if that makes sense, and since they're equal to constants.

Comment: Elementary row operations are equivalent to multiplication by certain nonsingular matrices. What matrix multiplication corresponds to $R2\to R2+oldR3$? Matrix multiplication can only form linear combinations of the rows that are present at the time, not pull them out a back pocket.

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the second equation by $-1$ and adding to the first we get
$$-y+z-t=0$$
multiplying the last by $(-1)$ and adding to the first we have
$$y-z+t=0$$
this is the same equation like above, we can say
$$y=z-t$$ where $z,t$ arbitrary real numbers, now you can compute $x$

Comment: Does that mean $z$ and $t$ are parameters? Because there are $4$ unknown and $3$ equations, so I'd think there are only one. Also, what do you do with that to compute $x$?